# In Ruby, how does the shovel operator (<<) work on two integers?

Tags: ruby, integer, operator-keyword

I'm a beginner/intermediate Ruby learner and I ran something I didn't understand. I looked around **stackoverflow** but couldn't find a clear, concise answer so that's why I'm creating a new question.

If given a number a and b, what is the result r, when r equals:

```
a << b
```

In particular, I'm looking for a universal equation that denotes the relationship between the three variables. Also, insight into how Ruby works under the hood is welcomed but secondary.

FYI, I'm using repl.it at "https://repl.it/languages/ruby" if it helps.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: << is more commonly referred to as the binary or bitwise left shift operator.
EDIT2 as per Andrey Deineko: This question is different than the other post listed at the top because in the other post, there was no clear, concise answer to how it works. It simply stated that it was a bitwise left shift operator and showed a few examples of outputs with that method. In particular, I was looking for how it works on integers or fixnums only. It seems the other post was about the general use of the operator. To reiterate, this question is different because it applies specifically to how it works on integers and as such, the answer below goes a bit more into detail as to how it works on a binary level.

Comment: Ruby, like C++, uses the `<<` operator for a lot of things other than what it was originally intended for. Maybe that's the influence of things like the Bash shell where `>` and `<` take on particular meanings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operation is called “bitwise left shift” and is easily googlable by this term.

In short, it takes the binary representation of the LHO and shifts it to the left by count, specified as RHO.

Consider you have `5 << 2`. `5` is represented by (64bits):

```
0000 0000 0000 0101
```

Left shift by `2` would be:

```
00 0000 0000 0101 00 # = 0000 0000 0001 0100
```

or, in turn, `20`. Let’s check:

```
5 << 2
#⇒ 20
```

Due to the nature of binary numeral base system, left shift is equivalent to multiplying by the respective power of `2`. That said,

```
m << n ≡ m × 2ⁿ

5 << 4 #⇒ 5 × 2⁴ ≡ 80
#⇒ 80
```

Comment: Put another way: `5 << 2` is the same as `5 * 2 ** 2` or in general form `x << y` is `x * 2 ** y`.

Comment: @tadman I believe it is exactly the same as what I put in the last snippet: m << n ≡ m × 2ⁿ, isn’t it?

Comment: Exactly the same. I just thought Ruby notation might be educational as well.

Comment: Sweet! This makes sense. Thanks for your reply. The only thing now is this is leading me towards needing to learn more about 64 bit and how it affects the bitwise left shift operator.

Comment: 64bits (here it states for the hardware platform architecture) does not affect the bitwise shift anyhow, it affects the amount of zeroes and ones in the binary representation.

Comment: That's amazing. Can't believe I've only discovered this today, however many years in to ruby. Thanks for this very helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Ruby version, integer may inherit `<<` from [Fixnum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3C), or [Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3C)

Either way the operation is the same: the integers assigned to `a` and `b` are interpreting `<<` as a bitwise left shift operator. You can see what's going on behind the scenes here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3C

There's an interesting discussion of this operator here: [Clarification on the Ruby << Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730303/clarification-on-the-ruby-operator)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the extra resources